# Using ng-repeat on 1d array to create 2d display with fixed width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

Is it possible to create a something like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
and create the following on bootstrap using `ngRepeat`:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4">1</div>
<div class="span4">2</div>
<div class="span4">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4">4</div>
<div class="span4">5</div>
<div class="span4">6</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4">7</div>
<div class="span4">8</div>
<div class="span4">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to create a directive to accomplish that. You can create this mark up but it wont work as per boot-strap rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your list in a scope variable called, for example, `myList` then you can use a watch that looks something like this

```
$scope.rows = [];
$scope.$watchCollection('myList', function(source) {
  $scope.rows = [];
  for(var i=0; i<source.length; i+=3) {
    var row = [];
    for(var j=i; j<i+3 && j<source.length; j++) {
      row.push(source[j]);
    }
    $scope.rows.push(row);
  }
});
```

to maintain a version of the list split into rows (conveniently called `rows`). This can be used in nested `ng-repeat`s to do what you want. I have written an example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/y6fCIz?p=preview). You may need to expand the preview window to get the `span`s to show on the correct lines, but the markup is correct. It's just bootstrap being responsive.

This is just an example to show how you might go about doing this though - I agree with @defau1t that you should be creating a directive for this.

*Edit*: Example directive [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gV8b1n?p=preview)